# Download forecast values from tsibble (Fable)

Tags: tsibble, fable-r

I'm sure this is a simple question, but relatively new here.  I'm trying to extract the forecasted values in a CSV/table I can use outside of R.  I followed along with the multiple series example from here: https://www.mitchelloharawild.com/blog/fable/  .  I'm trying to extract the 2 years forecasted data that's completed in this step:

```
fit %>% 
  forecast(h = "2 years") %>% 
  autoplot(tourism_state, level = NULL)
```

I can see the 3 models in the autoplot, but can't figure out how to get the forecasted values from the Fit tsibble.  Any help is appreciated.  It looks like there's quite a bit of information that can be genreated (forecast intervals, etc.), so if there's somewhere I can reference on how to parse through what all can be downloaded and how please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forecasted values of a fable can be saved to a csv using `readr::write_csv()`.

When used with columns that are not in a flat format (such as forecast distributions or intervals), the values will be stored as character strings and information will be lost. Before writing to a file, you should flatten these structures by extracting their components into separate columns.

You can use `unpack_hilo()` to extract the `lower`, `upper`, and `level` values within a `<hilo>` to create a flat data structure. Alternatively you can access the components of a `<hilo>` with `$`, for example: `my_interval$lower`.

Comment: Thank you so much!